# How to use a text file as a template?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to load a text file and use as a template in python.

This is my example code:

```
for x in range(1,10):
    tmp = open("test.md","r").read()
    print(tmp)
```

This is my text file (`test.md`):

```
{ x }
```

This is my current output:

```
{ x }
{ x }
{ x }
{ x }
{ x }
{ x }
{ x }
{ x }
{ x }
```

I want this output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
....
```

Python 3 accepts `{ variable }` in string ... how I can do that in this situation? Using f-string?

Comment: Maybe you should use some `jinja` template. Well, depending on the use case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing something more rather than just print, i would suggest you use [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/) (which is mainly used for html templating) like,

**Requirments:**

Create a virtualenv:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Install the `jinja2` package:

```
$ pip install jinja2
```

**Files:**

```
$ cat tpl.py
import sys
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('.') # directory of template file
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)

template = env.get_template(sys.argv[1]) # load template file

output = template.render(values=range(10))
print(output)


$ cat tpl.txt
{% for value in values -%}
    {{ value }} 
{% endfor %}
```

**Output:**

```
$ python tpl.py tpl.txt
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9
```

Try another template:

```
$ cat tpl2.txt
{% for value in values -%}
{% if value < 5 %}
{{- value }}
{% endif %}    
{%- endfor %}


$ python tpl.py tpl2.txt
0
1
2
3
4
```

A little too much ? :)

Answer (score 7):

You read a string from the file; you need to invoke its `format` method.

```
with open("test.md", "r") as f:
    tmp = f.read()

for x in range(1, 10):
    print(tmp.format(x))
```

Note that the `x` in your template is unrelated to the name of the variable you use in the `for` loop.

As-is, this will fail, because `'{ x }'` is a different format than `'{x}'`. Either edit the file to provide valid formats, modify the template in-memory (e.g., `tmp.replace(" ", "")`), or provide the exact key in the call to `format` (`tmp.format(**{" x ": x})`).

Comment: I like that this uses `with` and only reads the template file once.

Comment: You also probably would want to remove the spaces in your text file: `{x}`